# Eclipse class not found error when I have both dependent and parent project in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat

I have two projects in eclipse, **Project A** and **Project B**. Project B is dependency to Project A. I am trying to deploy Project A in tomcat v9.0. I am getting an error as class(which is inside Project B) not found error. But when I release and give the Project B's released version in Project A there is no issues. Can someone help me with this?.

> Mar 23, 2018 9:37:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: className at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)   at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:490)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)

Comment: you can create snapshot version on your local, and add the dependency on the dependent project, because without adding the dependency it will give an error.

Comment: I have tried the same. It was working, but now I am facing this issue.